# How to retrieve more than 1000 rows from Parse.com?

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I have been using Parse to retrieve a data for a list view. Unfortunately they limit requests to 100 by default to a 1000 max. I have well over that 1000 max in my class. I found a link on the web which shows a way to do it on iOS but how would you do it on Android? [Web Link](http://alexefish.com/post/29843064002/fetching-every-row-of-a-table-with-parse-and-pfquery)

I am currently adding all the data into a arraylist in a loop until all items are complete (100) then adding them to the list

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I have figured out how to achieve my goal:

**Declare Global Variable**

```java
private static List<ParseObject>allObjects = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
```

**Create Query**

```java
final ParseQuery parseQuery = new ParseQuery("Objects");
parseQuery.setLimit(1000);
parseQuery.findInBackground(getAllObjects());
```

**Callback for Query**

```java
int skip=0;
FindCallback getAllObjects(){
    return new FindCallback(){
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                allObjects.addAll(objects);
                 int limit =1000;
                if (objects.size() == limit){
                    skip = skip + limit;
                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Objects");
                    query.setSkip(skip);
                    query.setLimit(limit);
                    query.findInBackground(getAllObjects());
                }
                //We have a full PokeDex
                else {
                    //USE FULL DATA AS INTENDED
                }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: What's the initial value of skip?

Comment: The initial value should be 0, as you want to start at the first record, and keep skipping the limit until you have all the objects

Comment: i had to make 'skip' var to global for get this code  working. but axcept for that code is greate

Comment: Not sure why but it is not working for me. it's asking me to implement two: `done(List objects, ParseException e)` and `done(Object o, Throwable throwable) `
 methods and it is always calling the one with the one object

Answer (score 14):

Here is a **JavaScript** version without promises..

These are the global variables (collections are not required, just a bad habit of mine)..

```
   ///create a collection of cool things and instantiate it (globally)
    var CoolCollection = Parse.Collection.extend({
       model: CoolThing
    }), coolCollection = new CoolCollection();
```

This is the "looping" function that gets your results..

```
//recursive call, initial loopCount is 0 (we haven't looped yet)
function getAllRecords(loopCount){

    ///set your record limit
    var limit = 1000;

    ///create your eggstra-special query
     new Parse.Query(CoolThings)
            .limit(limit)
            .skip(limit * loopCount) //<-important
            .find({
             success: function (results) {
                 if(results.length > 0){

                     //we do stuff in here like "add items to a collection of cool things"
                     for(var j=0; j < results.length; j++){
                         coolCollection.add(results[j]);
                     }

                     loopCount++; //<--increment our loop because we are not done

                     getAllRecords(loopCount); //<--recurse
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     //our query has run out of steam, this else{} will be called one time only
                     coolCollection.each(function(coolThing){
                        //do something awesome with each of your cool things
                     });
                 }
            },
             error: function (error) {
                //badness with the find
             }
         });
}
```

This is how you call it (or you could do it other ways):

```
getAllRecords(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

**JAVA**

So after 5 years, 4 months the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18696377/2139488) of @SquiresSquire needed some changes to make it work for me, and I would like to share it with you.

```
private static List<ParseObject>allObjects = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
```

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("CLASSNAME");
parseQuery.setLimit(1000);
parseQuery.findInBackground(getAllObjects());
```

```
FindCallback <ParseObject> getAllObjects() {
    return new FindCallback <ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                allObjects.addAll(objects);
                int limit = 1000;
                if (objects.size() == limit) {
                    skip = skip + limit;
                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("CLASSNAME");
                    query.setSkip(skip);
                    query.setLimit(limit);
                    query.findInBackground(getAllObjects());
                }
                //We have a full PokeDex
                else {
                    //USE FULL DATA AS INTENDED
                }
            }
        }
    
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

> **IMPORTANT None of the answers here are useful if you are using open**
>   **source parse server then it does limit 100 rows by default but you can**
>   **put any value in query,limit(100000) //WORKS
>    No need for recursive**
>   **calls just put the limit to number of rows you want**.

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/5383

Answer (score 3):

In **C#** I use this recursion:

```
private static async Task GetAll(int count = 0, int limit = 1000)
{
    if (count * limit != list.Count) return;
    var res = await ParseObject.GetQuery("Row").Limit(limit).Skip(list.Count).FindAsync();
    res.ToList().ForEach(x => list.Add(x));
    await GetAll(++count);
}
```

**JS** version:

```
function getAll(list) {
    new Parse.Query(Row).limit(1000).skip(list.length).find().then(function (result) {
        list = list.concat(result);
        if (result.length != 1000) {
            //do here something with the list...
            return;
        }

        getAll(list);
    });
}
```

Usage: `GetAll()` in C#, and `getAll([])` in JS.

I store all rows from the class `Row`in the `list`. In each request I get 1000 rows and skip the current size of the `list`. Recursion stops when the current number of exported rows is different from the expected.

Answer (score 3):

> ****EDIT : Below answer is redundant because open source parse server doesn't put any limit on max rows to be fetched**

```
 //instead of var result = await query.find();
    query.limit(99999999999);//Any value greater then max rows you want
    var result = await query.find();**
```

Original answer:

**Javascript / Cloud Code**

Here's a clean way working for all queries

```
async function fetchAllIgnoringLimit(query,result) {
  const limit = 1000;
  query.limit(limit);
  query.skip(result.length);

  const results = await query.find();
  result = result.concat(results)

  if(results.length === limit) {
    return await fetchAllIgnoringLimit(query,result );
  } else {
    return result;
  }

}
```

And here's how to use it

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
//instead of var result = await query.find();
var result = await fetchAllIgnoringLimit(query,new Array());
console.log("got "+result.length+" rows")
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this version, but I think there's an error with your `results.length === limit` check because you have already reassigned `result` to the combined results.  It might be safer all around to replace `result = ...` with a new variable, such as `const combined = ...` and pass that to the next call to `fetchAllIgnoringLimit`

Comment: IMP - You should not use this above answer.Open source parse server doesnt restrict max 1000 rows See my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60887036/9752209

Answer (score 1):

YAS (Yet Another Solution!) Using `async()` and `await()` in **javascript**.

```
async parseFetchAll(collected = []) {
  let query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
  const limit = 1000;

  query.limit(limit);
  query.skip(collected.length);

  const results = await query.find();

  if(results.length === limit) {
    return await parseFetchAll([ ...collected, ...results ]);
  } else {
    return collected.concat(results);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A **Swift 3** Example:

```
var users    = [String] ()
var payments = [String] ()
///set your record limit
let limit = 29
//recursive call, initial loopCount is 0 (we haven't looped yet)
func loadAllPaymentDetails(_ loopCount:  Int){
    ///create your NEW eggstra-special query
    let paymentsQuery  = Payments.query()
    paymentsQuery?.limit = limit
    paymentsQuery?.skip  = limit*loopCount
    paymentsQuery?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
        if let objects = objects {
            //print(#file.getClass(),"  ",#function,"  loopcount: ",loopCount,"      #ReturnedObjects: ",  objects.count)
            if objects.count > 0 {
                //print(#function, " no. of objects :", objects.count)
                for paymentsObject in objects {
                    let user   = paymentsObject[Utils.name] as! String
                    let amount = paymentsObject[Utils.amount] as! String
                    self.users.append(user)
                    self.payments.append(amount)
                }
                //recurse our loop with increment because we are not done
                self.loadAllPaymentDetails(loopCount + 1); //<--recurse
            }else {
                //our query has run out of steam, this else{} will be called one time only
                //if the Table had been initially empty, lets inform the user:
                if self.users.count == 1 {
                    Utils.createAlert(self, title: "No Payment has been made yet", message: "Please Encourage Users to make some Payments", buttonTitle: "Ok")
                }else {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }else if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }else {
            print("Unknown Error")
        }
    })
}
```

*adapted from @deLux_247's example above.*

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using CloudCode... Make a custom function you can call that will enumerate the entire collection and build a response from that but a wiser choice would be to paginate your requests, and fetch the records 1000 (or even less) at a time, adding them into your list dynamically as required.

Comment: an example would have been helfpful.

Answer (score 0):

**GENERIC VERSION For SWIFT 4:**

Warning: *this is not tested!*

An attempt to adapt nyxee's answer to be usable for any query:

```
func getAllRecords(for query: PFQuery<PFObject>, then doThis: @escaping (_ objects: [PFObject]?, _ error: Error?)->Void) {
    let limit = 1000
    var objectArray : [PFObject] = []
    query.limit = limit
    func recursiveQuery(_ loopCount:  Int = 0){
        query.skip  = limit * loopCount
        query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
            if let objects = objects {
                objectArray.append(contentsOf: objects)
                if objects.count == limit {
                    recursiveQuery(loopCount + 1)
                } else {
                    doThis(objectArray, error)
                }
            } else {
                doThis(objects, error)
            }
        })
    }
    recursiveQuery()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for C# .NET

```
 List<ParseObject> allObjects = new List<ParseObject>();
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = ParseObject.GetQuery("Class");
 int totalctr = await query1.CountAsync()
 for (int i = 0; i <= totalctr / 1000; i++)
 {
     ParseQuery<ParseObject> query2 = ParseObject.GetQuery("Class").Skip(i * 1000).Limit(1000);
     IEnumerable<ParseObject> ibatch = await query2.FindAsync();
     allObjects.AddRange(ibatch);
 }
```