# Parse.com Android: Number of ParseObjects I can pin to the Local Datastore?

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk, parse-platform

I'm building an Android health & fitness app and would like to store some health data.

To be able to use the app without internet connection I'm using the Parse Local Datastore exactly as described here: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#localdatastore-caching

Everything works fine as long I have less then 100 ParseObjects pinned to the Local Datastore. If I have more ParseObjects, only the first 100 will be loaded.

So I would like to know if there's a way to increase the maximum number of ParseObjects I can pin to the Local Datastore or some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that a query on the Local Datastore has the same limitations as a query on the network.

Therefore you can set the maximum limit to 1000 with:

```
parseQuery.setLimit(1000); // limit to at most 1000 results
```

If you want to query for more than 1000 ParseObjects, you can follow this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18696377/954811 (it works the same on Local Datastore).