# Parse.com always returns a maximum of 100 records, same having "limit = 1000"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, request

I have an iOS app that receives data from the PARSE.COM. 
How did not know nothing about 'parse.com' , I used the tutorial "http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1".

The synchronization occurs only from the server to the device (iOS), and one time the object is added to the device, it should not be inserted again.

Turns out I got 131 objects in a class and 145 in another, but the Parse.com always returns me the first 100 items, even those already are in the device (iOS).

The worst thing is that in my code I have a variable "limit" in "request" that should work, but does not work for me.

I need your help, please ...

Code:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)GETRequestForAllRecordsOfClass:(NSString *)className updatedAfterDate:(NSDate *)updatedDate
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
    NSDictionary *paramters = nil;
    if (updatedDate) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.'999Z'"];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

        NSString *jsonString = [NSString 
                                stringWithFormat:@"{\"updatedAt\":{\"$gte\":{\"__type\":\"Date\",\"iso\":\"%@\"}}}", 
                                [dateFormatter stringFromDate:updatedDate]];

        //That's line of 'paramters' is from original tutorial Raywenderlich
       // paramters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:jsonString forKey:@"where"];

        //This line was add for the autors of tutorial in a comment from your blog, and he say that has work, but not for me =(
        paramters = @{@"where" : jsonString, @"limit" : @(1000)};

    }
    request = [self GETRequestForClass:className parameters:paramters];
    return request;
}​
```

The print of variable "request" after this method is this:

```
URL: https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Substancia?where=%7B%22updatedAt%22%3A%7B%22%24gte%22%3A%7B%22__type%22%3A%22Date%22%2C%22iso%22%3A%222014-09-23T02%3A13%3A01.999Z%22%7D%7D%7D&limit=1000
```

Why do same having the variable "LIMIT = 1000", the parse.com every returns me 100 items?
And even that returns 100 items, why do in the next time he does the "request" he it does not catch the next 100 since the other 100 registers earlier have already been entered?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have to ask: why are you using the REST queries in iOS? You could simply use the built-in iOS query system instead.

Comment: Generally speaking "limit" will only limit the number of results returned. There is probably another parameter to use to tell the server your offset.

Comment: Ryan, bacause i used an tutorial (raywenderlich)... =S

Comment: Ian. But if the limit is 1000 (for example) and I have 150 items in the server of PARSE.COM, this 150 items does not exceed the limit, then the "request" should bring 150 items, right? 
The problem is that he always behind 100, and items are the same. =(

Comment: there are nice solutions in amany languages here: [How to retrieve more than 1000 rows from Parse.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246991/how-to-retrieve-more-than-1000-rows-from-parse-com?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

(Answering here since I don't have enough reputation to comment.)

- For the `limit=1000` not seeming to work: perhaps the "where" clause (i.e. constraining to items with `updatedAt` value >= 2014-09-23T02:13:01.999Z) is limiting results to less than 1000?
- (To Ian's point) There is a 'skip' parameter that tells the API how many items to skip ahead, for pagination. i.e. `limit=100&skip=100` to see page 2.

Comment: Gabby, thank you for your help. 
- Apparently  not is this, because the date of the "last update" that I use in the "where" is lower than the "update date" of all 131 or 145 items I have in PARSE.COM. 
So should be bring all, because they have not been updated yet on the device... 
- I saw the clause "skipe" but it does not work for me because in my case I got the limit in 1000 on the "request" and only 145 items on PARSE.COM, then it is not overflow the limit. = (

Comment: Hmm some things to try: 1) Can you try LOWERING the limit to 50 and seeing if you indeed see fewer results? 2) Can you post the code for "GETRequestForClass:parameters" and also the code that handles the response from parse (if that is different); just to rule out that there's something going on there that applies a 100 limit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think [this](http://alexefish.tumblr.com/post/29843064002/fetching-every-row-of-a-table-with-parse-and) is what you're looking for. A great solution on how to retrieve all the objects from Parse instead of the max limit i.e. 1000.