# Parse only retrieves 100 items and I've got 108

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm having a problem. Yesterday my database exceeded 100 items. In my app I'm doing my query like:

```
PFQuery *languageQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Language"];
[languageQuery whereKey:@"code" equalTo:_languageCode];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"DrinksLocal"];
[query whereKey:@"language" matchesQuery:languageQuery];

[query includeKey:@"country"];
[query includeKey:@"types"];
[query includeKey:@"drinks"];
[query includeKey:@"matching"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
    // do some stuff
    } else {
        DDLogError(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

How can I solve this? I thought parse did pagination in the background so you didn't have this problem?

Setting the limit to 1000 is a temporary solution. How can I really solve this for like 1000+ items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set limit for querying for more than 100 items. Check Docs [Here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-query-constraints)

`query.limit = 10; // limit to at most 10 results`

For more than 1K rows, you have to follow paging - Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246991/parse-retrieve-more-then-1000-rows) and
[here](https://parse.com/questions/paging-through-more-than-10000-results).

Comment: Duplicate question duplicate answer. OP should have researched this as it gets a plethora of hits.